# Static block cache home page not work

Tags: magento

i have two stores view,
store view 1 and store view 2
i have been creating 2 cms pages with the same content
ex:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_home_page"}}
```

and i go to cms --> static block and create 2 blocks with identifer: `block_home_page`

i go to the frontend and switch store view , the content of static block changed folowing current store view, but when i enable caching in the back end, the static block at frontend has not change, what is happening , every body can help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You would get more attention if you gave explicit code.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which is the magento version ?

Comment: If you're on CE 1.9 or EE 1.14 then this is a common issue asked frequently on the Magento StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you are using ***two static blocks with same identifier***. A block identifier is used to uniquely identify a static block. Since you are using same identifier for two blocks, Magento is unable to find the correct one while it caches the content.

Hence you can use two different static blocks in two differnent CMS Pages. But make sure static block identifiers are different.

---

**Side Note**

It seems that there are some bugs in Magento static block cacheing in the latest release of Magento. (version = 1.9.2.0). You can find the ***[exact problem here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues)*** and the solution is using modules [***such as this***](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache). (this is my own module. It is free though)

Comment: The identifier can be the same between store views

Comment: @scrowler please explain how magento recognize each static block individually if you are using same identifier for multiple static blocks (even if in different store views)

Comment: You can have many static blocks with the same identifier but that can apply to either different stores or different design packages (essentially stores). In this case, if you have three stores and three blocks called "foobar", one assigned to each store, Magento grabs the block identified by "foobar" that is assigned to the current store if it exists, and if it doesn't exist then it goes to whichever one may be globally assigned

Comment: @scrowler That makes sense. What about two static blocks have global assignment and no store-wise seperation ?

Comment: Then it would get confused and probably use the one with the lowest entity ID

Comment: @RajeevKTomy thank you so much it's work well and i'm using this link https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache